# Error when trying to start Boost thread

Tags: iphone, xcode, multithreading, boost

I've been using Boost threads in my iPhone application for a while, and have just stumbled upon a problem. Every so often, when the application tries to start such a thread, it throws an error while trying to call `start_thread()`, and the application crashes.

I don't really know where to begin debugging this - it doesn't seem obvious from the debugger why the boost thread can't be initialised. It should be noted that this only happens after the application has been running for a while, and after several threads have already been started successfully.

I've recently been working on the UI, and I've been using the following command to ensure that every update to the UI takes place immediately upon being called:

```
[myViewController performSelectorOnMainThread : @ selector(show_myButton) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

While that command seems to work, and the UI is updated immediately (where before it was delayed), I fear it might be responsible for the boost thread problems I'm having. Does that sound likely? Has anyone experienced anything like this before, and have any suggestions as to what might be wrong?

Here's the code that is meant to start the thread:

```
void ObjectiveCPlusPlusInterface::startMyThread(void* a, myObject* b)
{
 boost::thread AVPlayerThread = boost::thread(&ObjectiveCPlusPlusInterface::myThreadFunction, this, a, b);
}
```

(where a & b are variables)

```
void ObjectiveCPlusPlusInterface::myThreadFunction(void* a, myObject* b)
{
 ...
}
```

As you can see, `startMyThread()` tries to start a boost thread, which performs the function `myThreadFunction()`. However, `myThreadFunction()` is not reached, as starting the boost thread throws an error.

Comment: Can you please post the code that includes creating the thread, up to the point of joining it? (Omit irrelevant intermediate code.)

Comment: Also, looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2109483/596781), are you sure you're catching exceptions?

Comment: Thanks - I've now added the code. As regards catching exceptions, no, I'm not sure I'm doing this - and, looking at your answer below, I don't entirely understand how to do this. Could you give me any advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking [at the manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.callable_constructor), we see that the `boost::thread` constructor can throw an exception. Make sure that you check for that:

```
try
{
    boost::thread AVPlayerThread(&ObjectiveCPlusPlusInterface::myThread, this, a, b);

    AVPlayerThread.detach();   // or join()?
}
catch (boost::thread_resource_error const &)
{
    // resource error (print a diagnostic!)
}
catch (...)
{
    // some other exception (print a diagnostic!)
}
```

---

*Update:* After your edit, I see that you don't join or detach the thread! That's not allowed.

You can put the entire block above literally inside your `startMyThread` function.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you give me any advice as to how to implement this in my code? I've not used anything like this before. Also, I currently have no `join()` or `detach()` calls. Am I right in thinking that `join()` will mean the main thread waits until the boost thread returns? If so, that won't do for my purposes. Is `detach()`, then, what I should be using?

Comment: @user1295558: correct, `join()` will block until the thread function returns. `detach()` will make the thread run indefinitely. I've updated the post so that you should be able to paste it literally into your function.

Comment: Thanks. I've detached the thread after it's initialised, as well as putting in the catches you recommend. Since I made that change, the error hasn't occurred, but, since it was only happening occasionally before, it's hard to tell whether or not the problem is fixed. I'll continue testing and see whether or not it resurfaces. Did you think, in advising me to detach the thread, that that might be a solution to my problem?

Comment: @user1295558: You *must* either detach or join every single `boost::thread` that you start; otherwise your program has undefined behaviour (i.e. is broken). This isn't a matter of choice!

Comment: Great, thanks. I thought everything was Ok as my application worked for a long time without detaching the `boost::thread`s, and it was only when playing with the UI that I started seeing this crash. In your opinion, will detaching the threads likely have put at end to the problem I was seeing whereby the application occasionally crashed when starting such a thread?

Comment: @user1295558: This is a strange question in view of my previous comment: *Not* detaching/joining your thread is *definitely* broken. So yes, please do detach your thread. (Or manage your threads so that you can join them at shutdown time.) I'm pretty sure your program has *always* crashed upon exiting till now.

Comment: I see that not detaching/joining the thread is definitely broken, and my program probably did crash on exiting up until now. What I'm really asking is whether the change I've made - that is, detaching `boost::thread`s - is likely to have solved the issue my original question was concerning - that is, a `boost::thread` trying to start but failing to do so. Essentially, I'm really glad to have fixed my code inasmuch as it was incorrect before and probably crashing every time it exited, but I'd also like to know whether this is likely to have solved the `start_thread()` error. What do you think?

Comment: @user1295558: Well, I don't know what your thread is doing in its entirety, but immediate detaching seems like a viable solution for the time being. Personally, I don't like detaching, as I prefer to keep track of all my threads and join them when appropriate, but that's more difficult to design. So... go with it :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's great. Really grateful for all your help on this - it all seems to be working now.

Comment: @KerrekSB well, not exactly. Joining/detaching is mandatory only if BOOST_THREAD_VERSION==2 and BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_THREAD_DESTRUCTOR_CALLS_TERMINATE_IF_JOINABLE is defined.

Comment: @IgorR.: OK, cool, thanks! For `std::thread` in C++11, it's definitely mandatory :-)